# How to select a especify tab index?

Tags: vb.net, tabindex

I need to select the tabindex "0", I've two buttons which have tab index equals to 0, with conditions one of them disapear and the other apears (and vice versa).

I'm using for focusing:

```
BTN_Deletar.Select()
BTN_Limpar.Select()
BTN_Deletar.Focus()
BTN_Limpar.Focus()
```

I need something like

```
Tabindex.Select = 0
```

Comment: Firstly, don't use `Focus` at all.  As the documentation states, `Select` is what an application developer uses to focus a particular control.

Comment: As for the question, there is no such syntax.  To focus a control you call its `Select` method or assign it to the `ActiveControl` property of the form.  That's it, that's all.  If you want to choose that control by some particular condition then you need to do that first.  If you want to find a control with a particular `TabIndex` value then do that.  Once you have the desired control, call its `Select` method.

Comment: If you know those are the two buttons, then you just need to determine which one is supposed to be visible and do a "Select()" on that.  Not sure why you would care about the TabIndex since you know the buttons in question.

Comment: Furthermore, if you are talking about `Buttons` appearing and disappearing then you would need to either give them the same `Location` and `Size` or else call `Hide` and `Show` on them as required.

Comment: About Buttons, yes, I'm moving, hiding and showing them... They're ok...

Comment: Got it! Using Select now... I had problem with it, but it was because my tab order was wrong.